# Podman: how to resolve the hostname of a pod deployed using Kubernetes YAML

Tags: kubernetes, containers, microservices, podman, podspec

I'm using podman 4.5-dev
I have two pods deployed using:
*podman kube play foo.yaml*
*podman kube play bar.yaml*

I specified the pods' hostnames in the files, but they won't get resolved inside the containers.
I verified that the pods are in the same network.

Is there some DNS configuration missing? Should I use a Services? The official docs lack of a precise indication about this topic

Here's one of the two pods's YAML (the other one has the same keys with different values):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: postgres
  name: postgres
spec:
  hostname: postgres
  containers:
  - name: pgadmin-container
    image: docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      hostPort: 9876
```

Here's some terminal output that could be useful:

```bash
[daniele@localhost]$ podman pod inspect xptssrv |grep -ni network
25:          "HostNetwork": false,
34:          "Networks": [
35:               "podman-default-kube-network"
37:          "NetworkOptions": null,


[daniele@localhost]$ podman pod inspect postgres |grep -ni network
25:          "HostNetwork": false,
34:          "Networks": [
35:               "podman-default-kube-network"
37:          "NetworkOptions": null,



[daniele@localhost]$ podman network inspect podman-default-kube-network |grep "" -n
1:[
2:     {
3:          "name": "podman-default-kube-network",
4:          "id": "a4dcf21f020ee4e36651c11256cbe884182552e835eaaafd409153cd21dca4cc",
5:          "driver": "bridge",
6:          "network_interface": "cni-podman1",
7:          "created": "2023-02-21T23:03:25.800256942+01:00",
8:          "subnets": [
9:               {
10:                    "subnet": "10.89.0.0/24",
11:                    "gateway": "10.89.0.1"
12:               }
13:          ],
14:          "ipv6_enabled": false,
15:          "internal": false,
16:          "dns_enabled": false,
17:          "ipam_options": {
18:               "driver": "host-local"
19:          }
20:     }
21:]

[daniele@localhost pods]$ podman exec  xptssrv-xptssrv-container cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.1.6
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Can you share with us an example configuration that reproduces this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your network settings in `/etc/containers/net.d/podman-default-kube-network.conflist`
Change this line

```
"dns_enabled": false,
```

To this:

```
"dns_enabled": true,
```

Then reboot and up your yaml and try to resolve this:

```
postgres_pgadmin-container_1
```

Or maybe this:

```
postgres_postgres_1
```

### Edit1

Just copy the config file:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/containers/containers.conf /etc/containers/containers.conf
```

Then in the file change the network backend to netavark using the following command:

```
sed -i "/^\s*\#*\s*network_backend\s*=.*$/ s/^.*$/network_backend = \"netavark\"/" /etc/containers/containers.conf
```

**Notice:** I think it's better to restart you system in order to apply changes.

Comment: Hi, unluckily it did not work

Comment: you mean its not resolved? are you sure they are on the same network and you are using netavark network stack?

Comment: I got it your network has `dns_enabled: false`

Comment: I tried your solution, I found that the location of "podman-default-kube-network.conflist" is different on my system:

/home/daniele/.config/cni/net.d/podman-default-kube-network.conflist

However I edited it, removed the pods and the network, reapplied the YAML files but the network still has "dns_enabled": false.

Comment: By running podman as root the network config file is:
/etc/cni/net.d/podman-default-kube-network.conflist

Even when changing this file nothing happens... I removed the network and reapplied the YAML files

Comment: I even added the "network" flag to the YAML file, but podman doesn't create the network

Comment: You should create network your self and try to change your default network stack to netavark. Actually personally I use podman compose. It has support for network. If you use netavark it will be fixed i think. Search "change podman default network stack"

Comment: Try the edit part in answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252272/discussion-between-ali-javaheri-and-daniele-navarra).

Comment: by copying and replacing the containers.conf file as you suggested I was able to reach the pod by just using the pod name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please accept my answer? I appreciate very much.